# How to express duration of an activity?

Tags: time

For example I want to say "I ran 5km in 23mins 59 secs" or "It took me 23mins 59 secs to run 5k" or "It took me an hour to tidy my room" etc etc etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possibly a little different for each of your examples even though they mean the same thing.  However, the ones with "took" seem to emphasize more effort than the ones with "in", so it depends if you want to focus on that or not.

> - I ran 5km **in** 23mins 59secs　→　23分59秒 **で** 5キロメートル走った
> - It **took** me 23mins 59 secs to run 5k　→　5キロメートル走るのに23分59秒 **かかった**

Comment: Can someone help me?  Does the `5キロメートル走る` need an `を` or not?  It looks correct with it one minute, then incorrect the next.  Would it only need the `を` if it were something like `5キロメートルの距離`?

Comment: @Jamal:  Look at definition 7 [HERE](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A7&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=02864200) for that usage of `で`.

Comment: Thanks istrasci, I've actually never been on this the yahoo dictionary, however it looks pretty useful.

Comment: @istrasci: Maybe I am mistaking, but I thought that 〜のに is only used to say: "Although". So it can be used also in other situations?

Comment: @Andry:  Yes, it can be used similarly to `～ために`.  See definition #3 [HERE](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=03358100).